# "Depoly to Cloud" option is not visible in the Anypoint studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

Version: 6.0.1 WIN 64 bit

i am trying to deploy the application to the cloud directly from the Anypoint Studio. But there is no such option when right clicking the project , please help.
[image]

Comment: Please reinstall studio with all latest updates and try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in `Project Explorer View` that's the reason you are unable to see `Cloud Deployment`. Need to shift to `package Explorer` view as seen in the below picture which is one option

[image]

Second option: Go to window in eclipse->Reset Perspective. It will reset your view to default one.Right on your Project-> Deploy to Anypoint Platform->select cloud

Your Installation should be alright, needn't require to reinstall the Anypoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked...was a silly question i know :P

Comment: @Deepsss No worries. Kind of does happen for everyone in other scenario's.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Cloudhub software in Anypoint studio, Go to Help--> Install New Software--> Click All--> search Cloudhub and select Mule CloudHub Connector Mule Studio Extension and download it.[snapshot of how to install cloudhub software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xra40.png)

After installing right click on project and go to Deploy to anypoint platform-->cloudhub